# List selections from two different multiple select dropdowns

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

Hi I'm trying to aggregate selections taken from different multiple selects but it only pulls from one of them. I'll eventually have like 15 different ones (they're all hidden and shown by another dropdown). http://jsfiddle.net/wZauw/1/

```
      <p></p>                               
    <div id="accounting" class="selector subcontent">
                           <select id="trade_select_accounting" multiple class="selector wrap-left">
                                   <option>Auditing</option>
                                   <option>Bookkeeping</option>        
                           </select>

                           </div>

                           <div id="administration" class="selector subcontent">
                                      <select id="trade_select_administration" multiple class="selector wrap-left">
                                              <option>Clerical</option>
                                              <option>Personnel</option>    
                                              <option>Training</option>    
                                      </select>

                                      </div>

<script>
function displayVals() {
                var multipleValues = $('[id^=trade_select_]').val() || [];
                $("p").html(" <b>Selected Trades:</b> " + 
                            multipleValues.join(", "));
              }

              $("select").change(displayVals);
              displayVals();
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

From the [docs](http://api.jquery.com/val/): *Description: Get the current value of the first element in the set of matched elements.*

You're going to need to manually aggregate the values, probably using a .each() on the returned array of elements.

Answer (score 0):

Try iterating through all of your `<select>` elements with an `.each` function and using the [:selected](http://api.jquery.com/selected-selector/) selector to grab all of your values.